# Is this code thread safe by using threadDictionary?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

```
+(NSString*)FromNumber:(NSNumber*)number
{
    NSString *key = akey;
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary] objectForKey:key];
    if(!numberFormatter)
    {
        numberFormatter = [self getDecimalNumberFormatterWithDigits:2];
        [numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];

        [numberFormatter setNegativeSuffix:@"%"];
        [numberFormatter setPositiveSuffix:@"%"];
        [numberFormatter setNilSymbol:@""];
        [numberFormatter setLocale:[ISMDateUtilities enUSPosixLocale]];

        [[[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary] setValue:numberFormatter forKey:key];
    }
    return [numberFormatter stringForObjectValue:number];
}
```

What I am curious is use of `threadDictionary` to synchronize a block of code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The thread-safety of this code depends on `akey` being a constant. If it is, then yes, this method is thread-safe because it doesn't share any state between threads. (I'm not sure what you mean by "synchronize," though — there's no synchronization at work here as far as I can see.)

Comment: The real question is *Do you really need a per-thread number formatter?!*   Seems odd to want to change the format of numbers depending on what thread is running?!  My best guess is that OP would be better served by a class method somewhere + `dispatch_once()` to initialize a singleton formatter in said method.

Comment: @bbum The docs for `NSNumberFormatter` state that the class isn't thread safe. But it is unclear whether this means a single formatter can format or parse multiple values from different threads at the same time or not.

Comment: Ah -- yeah -- that.  I forgot about that.  Still, a per-thread formatter screams "uncontrolled concurrency design".   I'd lean to a concurrency model a la CoreData;  tightly controlled and only one or two (main + worker) queues upon which formatting might take place.

Comment: You need a date and number formatter per thread often - as they are extremely slow to make on demand. So one per thread..

Comment: Since iOS 7 and macOS 10.9 NSNumberFormatter is thread safe, according to the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumberformatter